# Question about independence and calculating probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have this question as a homework and have tough time understanding it:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two independent events.
>
> (b) If we additionally know that $P(A|B) = 0.6$ and $P(B|A) = 0.3$, compute the probabilities of the following events:
>
> (i) at most one of $A$ or $B$
>
> (ii) either $A$ or $B$ but not both.

From my understanding, if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then the probability of $A$ is 0.6 and the probability of $B$ is 0.3, but I don’t understand what exactly am I supposed to do in (i) and (ii) and how to calculate it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Reword (i) as asking for $1 - \Pr(A\cap B)$.  That is to say, "*at most one of A or B*" is just another way of saying "*not the case that it is more than one of A and B*".  For (ii) that would be $\Pr(A\cup B) - \Pr(A\cap B)$.  Continue.

Comment: Are my assumptions for probabilities of A and B correct? @JMoravitz

Comment: That $\Pr(A)=0.6$?  Yes.  $\Pr(A)=\Pr(A\mid B)$ is one of the equivalent definitions of what it means for $A$ and $B$ to be independent events.